# Unable to save fetched data in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

I'm working on my front-end, and I've arrived at a roadblock. I'm trying to fetch data from my back-end, and it is actually fetching the data. But only after everything else? I'll show you.

```
$(function(){
    function GetURLId() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var path = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var id = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('?id=') + 4, path.lastIndexOf("?id") + 5)
        return id;
    }


    var url = 'https://localhost:5001/api/rental/byId/' + GetURLId();

        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) 
        .then(function(data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
            })
        });
});
```

So first I get which id I'm working with out of the URL. Then where the problem lays is the code under it. I'm able to fetch my data as it console.logs this:

```
id: 2
status: "Open"
damage: true
```

So the data does actually fetch from my back-end. But now, everytime I try to save the data it goes undefined. I've tried:

```
$(function(){
    var rental = []; // Added an array
    var url = 'https://localhost:5001/api/rental/byId/' + GetURLId();

        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) 
        .then(function(data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
                rental.push(rental[key] = data[key]);
            })
        });
    console.log(rental['id']); // Returns undefined
});
```

And:

```
var rental = []; // Added an array outside of the function
$(function(){
    var url = 'https://localhost:5001/api/rental/byId/' + GetURLId();

        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) 
        .then(function(data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
                rental.push(rental[key] = data[key]);
            })
        });
    console.log(rental['id']); // Returns undefined
});
```

But! With the last one where the rental is outside of the function, I can actually call it in the console. And in the console it actually does return the value.

```
Inside Console:
> rental["id"]
< 2
```

Lastly I've tried to check the value of the key and value inside of the fetch, like this:

```
$(function(){
    var url = 'https://localhost:5001/api/rental/byId/' + GetURLId();

        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) 
        .then(function(data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                if(key == "status" && data[key] != "Reserved") {
                    console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`); // Returns damage: undefined 3 times
                }
            })
        });
});
```

But this as well doesn't work. It returns damage: undefined 3 times in console.

So if anyone knows what is going on here it would be awesome!

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch requests are *asynchronous*. This means that when you call `fetch` it might take a while to complete it, so JavaScript allows the rest of the code to continue without blocking. So logging anything to the console **before** your request has finished will obviously result in an empty array.

Also, Arrays are index-, not name based in JavaScript. However, because arrays are essentially objects it still works, but you should **never** do the following below.

```
var rental = [];
rental['id'] = 'foo';
console.log(rental['id']);
```

Instead use a plain object which is meant to be used that way.

```
var rental = {};
rental['id'] = 'foo';
console.log(rental['id']);
```

In your last example you seem to do everything just fine. Are you sure your fetched `data` does not have a value of `undefined` in its structure? It would help to see what the data looks like.

Comment: First of all, making it a plain object results in the same way the array does, undefined. You can see what the data looks like in the second code fragment. It gets send as:
int id = 2;
string status = "Open";
boolean = damage: true;

Answer (score 0):

The answer: 2 errors in my code.
 - First I didn't properly account for the asynchronous nature of the code. 
 - Second, when trying to fix it with another then block and executing my code in there. I didn't return a value in the proceeding then block, but the forEach instead.

```
fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.json()) 
        .then(data => {
            var rentalStatus;
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                rental[key] = data[key];
                if(key == "status") {
                    rentalStatus = data[key];
                }
            })
            return rentalStatus;
        })
        .then(rentalStatus => {
            console.log(rental["id"]); // This does return the id now!
            if(rentalStatus == "Reserved") {
                $("#assign-items").removeClass("d-none");
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error:" + error);
        });
```